# How can I format separate date and time variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a $date and $time fields that are stored in my db, I would like to know how can I format these fields to display them in a different format?

e.g.

```
2010-05-09 -> 9th May 2010
```

and

```
13:00:00 -> 1:00PM
```

I have tried to use carbon but it returns the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 414: Unexpected data
>   found. Data missing

Comment: Just use Carbon, Laravel doesn't have any special classes or helpers to deal with dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `createFromFormat` method:

```
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '13:00:00')->format('g:iA');
```

The first argument is [the format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) of the date in your string.

Comment: This returns `2015-10-04 13:00:00`

Comment: I appended your solution with `->format()` and its working as desired

Answer (score 1):

You can always use PHP's `strtotime()` function and then manipulate the structure using `date()` as seen below.

```
$dateString = strtotime("2010-05-09");
$date = date("jS F, Y" ,$dateString);
echo $date;

$timeString = strtotime("13:00:00");
$time = date("g:i A" ,$timeString);
echo $time;
```

FWIW, I didn't realize you said specifically in Laravel. But I typed it all out, so figured I'd share anyways. Carbon (as mentioned above) *may* handle this in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I am aware of the native PHP solution but I'm looking for a Carbon solution if possible

Comment: I figured as much, but since I typed it up figured I'd post anyways. Check out Joseph's answer below.